# detect enterline when copy big text data into textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, copy-paste, enter

I want copy the big text data from any 
source(such as :other app,word,notepad,...) 
and paste to my textBox in my app.now I must be detect enterLine from  copied text.

I search so much but cant any solution.

tanx a lot

Comment: Please put your questions through a spell checker next time, the grammar is terrible. You should check the string being pasted in contains newlines, eg str.Contains("@\r\n");`
Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer:) Good Luck!

Comment: Did you find [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd.aspx) and [NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)?

Comment: you should sign up to stackoverflow instead of using anonymous account. -> that's always the best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create hook on default “Paste” event of WinForms TextBox control like below by creating custom textbox specially for your requirement.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class MyTextBox : TextBox 
    {
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            // Trap WM_PASTE:
            if (m.Msg == 0x302 && Clipboard.ContainsText())
            {
                var pastText = Clipboard.GetText().Replace('\n', ' ');
                if (pastText.Length > MaxLength)
                {
                    //Do Something 
                }
                else
                {
                    //Do Something 
                }
                this.SelectedText = pastText;
                return;
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```